# Python - is conda-pack cross platform and to what level

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, software-distribution, conda-pack

I am using conda-pack to package entire conda env and be able to bundle it with a script.

To what level of cross-platform can I except?
Any OS?
If built on Linux will any Linux work?
If built on Ubuntu will any Debian based work?
Same kernel version is needed?

What are the minimal requirements for two OS's to be compatible in that sense and can it be gauranteed?

Comment: There are a lot of questions (some of them might be considered too broad), that might not belong here. Better focus on the particular problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: AFAIK the main constraints on compatibilities of Conda package builds are architecture and C++ standard libraries. That is, if you pack for `linux-64`, one can only expect compatibility on other `x86_64` chips. Unsure about standard libs - [Conda Forge appears to have packaged some from the CentOS kernel](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/infrastructure.html#centos-sysroot-for-linux-platforms), which could be part of eliminating a hard dependency on the user's kernel libs. I'm no expert on this. Maybe [chat up with the CF folks](https://conda-forge.org/docs/orga/getting-in-touch.html)?

Comment: Also, these are nice questions to have answered in the `conda-pack` documentation itself. Consider [raising an Issue on the repo](https://github.com/conda/conda-pack/issues).

Comment: @CristiFati it is the main problem, I need to use a piece of code and need to know to what level I need to test